# two sub UIwindow in one UIWindow?

Tags: iphone, uiwindow

when we create iphone project, one UIWindow is created automatically.In that UIwindow UIViewcontroller's view  is added on that window.but i want to create one parent UIWindow
on which i have to add two sub window .In that sub windows i have add UIview controllers as normal...is it possible? any help please?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add any number of `UIView`s to your `UIWindow`, but not `UIWindow`s.

Comment: Yes you can. It's up to you to size and position them.

Comment: wrong answer, you can add a window as a subview to your keyWindow